# Not logging Console.ReadLine output?

Tags: c#

How can I NOT show the output when a user inserts something in Console.ReadLine so the console won't show what the user entered? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the input for non-security reasons, it is fairly tedious using `ReadKey` or various methods to hide the input. It can be done directly using the Windows API. Some of the sample code I found while searching for this didn't work immediately, but the code below did.

However, for cases where the input you are hiding is for security (e.g. a password), using `ReadKey` and `SecureString` would be preferred because `string` objects containing the password won't be generated (and then hang around in memory until GC).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{   
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsole, int dwMode);

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167(v=vs.85).aspx
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsole, out int dwMode);

        // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        // see docs for GetStdHandle. Use -10 for STDIN
        private static readonly IntPtr hStdIn = GetStdHandle(-10);

        // see docs for GetConsoleMode
        private const int ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 4;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Changing console mode");
             int mode;
             GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, out mode);
             SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, (mode & ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));
             Console.WriteLine("Mode set");
             Console.Write("Enter input: ");
             string value = Console.ReadLine();
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.WriteLine("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Console.ReadKey(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx) method and read the input character by character.

A workaround if you need to continue using `ReadLine` would be to set foreground and background colors to the same value.

If you want to just clear what the user entered, use `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method and write spaces to overwrite what user wrote or use `Console.Clear()` to clear the whole screen.

Comment: @Knagis I WANT to use Console.ReadLine to do what I want after the user pressed Enter, but I don't want to show what he wrote in the output. I thought about a way doing this - is to capture everything that's written in the console & store it. After the user pressed enter, clear the console - write the saved output and do whatever. How can I capture that though?

Comment: Extended the answer for that. Basically you need `Console.CursorTop` and `CursorLeft` properties to capture and position the cursor and then what you write to the console will overwrite what the user entered.

Comment: After I use ReadLine, I used:  Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
                Console.WriteLine("                      ");

Comment: you need to capture the values of Console.Cursor* properties before the user starts entering the data. Or at least try Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to hide the user input but the user can change the colors using Console->Properties

```
ConsoleColor forecolor = Console.ForegroundColor;
Console.ForegroundColor=Console.BackgroundColor;
string test=Console.ReadLine();
Console.ForegroundColor = forecolor;
```

Comment: This is a terrible hack.